# Fast user switching is greyed out

Tags: accounts

I am an administrator to my MBP, and should be able to [turn on fast user switching](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp2439/mac) to let more than one user stay logged in at the same time, right? But this is what I get:

[image]

What I'm missing?

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H512
```

Comment: Did you also click the lock icon to unlock? Is this MacBook managed and registered to a organization?

Comment: Everything is grayed out if not clicking the lock icon to unlock, and I think you've hit the nail on the head @howdytom, yes, my MacBook ***is*** managed and registered to a organization. I can accept that as an answer. Hmm, mind you, I tried from a local account, not registered to any organization, but the switch is grayed out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your MacBook Pro is registered to a organization and managed via a MDM Server. Thus you are not allowed to make adjustments to system preferences. Get in touch with your System Administrator.